# How to create a roster of students in java

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment problem that looks like this:

> (20 pts) Create a Student class with the following:
>
> - A private String variable named “name” to store the student’s name
> - A private integer variable named “UFID” that contains the unique ID number for this student
> - A private String variable named “DOB” to store the student’s date of birth
> - A private integer class variable named numberOfStudents that keeps track of the number of students that have been created so far
> - A public constructor Student(String name, int UFID, String dob)
> - Several public get/set methods for all the properties
>
>   ```
>   getName/setName
>   getUFID/setUFID
>   getDob/setDob
>   ```
> - Write a test program, roster.java, that keeps a list of current enrolled students.  It should have methods to be able to enroll a new
>     student and drop an existing student.

I'm not asking anyone to do this assignment for me, I just really need some general guidance. I think I have the `Student` class pretty well made, but I can't tell exactly what the `addStudent()` and `dropStudent()` methods should do - should it add an element to an array or something or just increments the number of students? The code I have so far looks like this.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int UFID;
    private String DOB;
    private static int numberOfStudents;

    public Student(String name, int UFID, String DOB) {
        this.name = name;
        this.UFID = UFID;
        this.DOB = DOB;
    }

    public String getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(String dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }

    public int getUFID() {
    return UFID; }

    public void setUFID(int uFID) {
    UFID = uFID; }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public void setNumberOfStudents(int numberOfStudents) {
        Student.numberOfStudents = numberOfStudents;
    }

    public static void addStudent(String name, int UFID, String DOB) {
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    public static void dropStudent(String name) {
        numberOfStudents--;
    }
}
```

Any guidance as I finish this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to use the homework tag; that's being deprecated.  Overall, what you have here is a model of a `Student`; consider what type of object ties all Students together.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment writes itself: you need a Roster class that owns and maintains a collection of Students:

```
public class Roster {
    private Set<Student> roster = new HashSet<Student>();

    public void addStudent(Student s) { this.roster.add(s); }

    public void removeStudent(Student s) { this.roster.remove(s); }
}
```

Comment: That is the sense of homeworks, some hints would have been made more sense

Comment: And then I'm sure you would have criticized me for not posting code or some other thing.  Funny, I never see answers from the folks like you, just comments suggesting that they consider themselves ultra-wise moderators.